# ember app kit, set additional model properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit

How can I add additional model properties after I find a model? (Or how can I access a route's params in setupController?

given a route

```
   this.resource('gallery', { path:'/gallery/:gallery_id' });
```

and a router `/routes/gallery.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('monkeys', { monkeyType: params.gallery_id });
        //can I add an additional property to the returned model here?
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var pageTitle = 'something related to params.gallery_id';
        //can I access route params in here?
        this.controllerFor("application").set('pageTitle', pageTitle);
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

Ideally I want to set the `pageTitle` property on the application controller to some `gallery_id` specific string, which is not returned by the api service.

the api returns the following, based on the url `/monkeys?monkeyType=someId`

```
{ "monkeys":[{ ... }, { ... }] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
export default Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var model = this.store.find('monkeys', { monkeyType; params.gallery_id });

        model.then(function(models) {
            this.controllerFor('application').set('pageTitle', models.get('firstObject.name'));
        }.bind(this));

        return model;
    }
});
```

Make sure you're returning `model` and **not** the promise returned by the `then` call. `store.find()` returns a `PromiseArray` while `then()` just returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the input - not quite what I was after though as the pageTitle relies on the params.gallery_Id, which is not in the model after it's returned from `this.store.find( ... )`

Comment: I don't see how that's an issue. Javascript has closures, and since `params.gallery_id` is most likely a primitive, you can use it in any nested function you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've ended up with:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return return {
            tag:params.gallery_id,
            monkeys:[]
        };
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var url = window.ENV.api + 'monkeys?monkeyType=' + model.tag;

        if(model.monkeys.length === 0){
            $.getJSON(url, function(json){
                model.monkeys.pushObjects(json.monkeys);
            });
        }

        this.controllerFor("application").set('pageTitle',
             this.getTitle(model.tag));

        controller.set('model', model);
    },
    getTitle: function(tag){
        //some arbitrary non-api lookup
    }
});
```

I'm not too keen on this solution, so would be happy to hear of improvements, or perhaps a version that makes use of Ember Data.